# Why my function named SubmitHash shows in Etherscan input field but not PublishHash?

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, etherscan

I deployed my contract in Ropsten Testnet with submitHash as a function name. I get function Name with value passed in Etherscan.

```
function submitHash(bytes32 pHash) external onlyOwner() {
       emit Submitted(pHash);
    }
```

and I get this in Etherscan input field

```
Function: submitHash(bytes32 proofHash) ***

MethodID: 0x08891a32
[0]:  69a013f23c52f5415ae41e64561a6948e08df59904925db53f0df74fd64a3833
```

But when I use publishHash as a function name in the Ropsten testnet and in mainnet

```
function publishHash(bytes32 pHash) external onlyOwner() {
       emit Submitted(pHash);
    }
```

I get this in input data field which is only a hash :

```
0x4d26695f69a013f23c52f5415ae41e64561a6948e08df59904925db53f0df74fd64a3833
```

I dont understand it as my code is all same except for the function name.
Can someone tell me the reason or a way to get publishHash in etherscan input field?

Comment: Do you have the hashes of both transactions? Is your contract verified? Etherscan uses verified contracts ABI to match the MethodID if it doesn't recognize it they will appear as a bytes sequence. The explorer for testnets like ropsten/rinkeby aren't updated immediately so even if you verify your contract it may toke a while until those changes are visible.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for the info. I verified the contract and now it is showing up